# Usage of ternary operator as placeholder

Tags: c, sorting, placeholder, ternary-operator, bubble-sort

I have a function  **bubble_sort_linkedList**  declared as,

```
void bubble_sort_linkedList(node *head);
```

The definition of the function (to sort in ascending order) goes like this :

```
void bubble_sort_linkedList(node *head){

            node *ptr, *lptr;
            int temp;   
            lptr = NULL; ptr = head;
            if(ptr == NULL || ptr->next == NULL)
                return;
            while(ptr != lptr){                 
                while(ptr->next != lptr){
                    if(ptr->next->value < ptr->value){    // Change the inequality sign             
                        temp = ptr->next->value;
                        ptr->next->value = ptr->value;
                        ptr->value = temp;                  
                    }
                    ptr = ptr->next;
                }
                lptr = ptr; 
                ptr = head;
            }   
            return;
        }
```

Now, I want the same function to sort in descending order too, with just one change of sign in commented line.

So, the change that I plan to make is :

```
void bubble_sort_linkedList(node *head, bool is_ascending);  //Prototype declaration
```

**is_ascending** is the decision passed from the main function.

Same function, but ternary operator used as placeholder (This is the part I am confused about, can ternary operator be used as shown below?)

```
void bubble_sort_linkedList(node *head, bool is_ascending){

    node *ptr, *lptr;
    int temp;   
    lptr = NULL; ptr = head;
    if(ptr == NULL || ptr->next == NULL)
        return;
    while(ptr != lptr){                 
        while(ptr->next != lptr){
            if(ptr->next->value ((is_ascending) ? <:>)  ptr->value){                            
                temp = ptr->next->value;
                ptr->next->value = ptr->value;
                ptr->value = temp;                  
            }
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        lptr = ptr; 
        ptr = head;
    }   
    return;
}
```

Comment: No you can't do that.  But it really wouldn't be terrible to add just one or two lines of code before that `if` test to evaluate the comparison you want.

Comment: It would work for function names, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it this way.  But you can write an expression that will do a conditional comparison:

```
if (is_ascending ? ptr->next->value < ptr->value : ptr->next->value > ptr->value) ...
```

If `is_ascending` is guaranteed to be `0` or `1`, here is an alternative with a single test that may be faster:

```
if ((ptr->next->value < ptr->value) == is_ascending) ...
```

Identical elements will be ordered differently, but the sort will still be correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you have tried it, you will have found out that you can't do that. The stuff before and after the colon must be a valid expression, which just a binary operator with nothing around it is not.

You can use the ternary operator, but in a more verbose way.

```
bool less = (is_ascending) 
          ? (ptr->next->value < ptr->value)
          : (ptr->next->value > ptr->value);

if (less) ...
```

Another possibility is to pass a comparison function (as `qsort` does)  instead of a boolean flag to determine how nodes are compared. This is more versatile, but arguably a bit of an overhead if you just want to distinguish between ascending and descending sorts.

(Also, `:>` and `<:`are [digraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) for the square brackets, so your code really isn't what it looks like at first sight.)

Comment: The choice of name is a tad confusing, or maybe philosophical: in some cases, `less` is more.

Comment: @chqrlie: Only to those who want to be confused. `less` refers to the ordering within the list, of course, not to the actual values. (The name is inspired by object-oriented languages where objects can be sorted when their class provides a `less` member function or overload a `<` operator.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the comparison operator like that, but instead, you can change the comparison itself.

If you really want to do a one-liner, you can do that :

```
if (((ptr->next->value - ptr->value < 0) && is_ascending) || ((ptr->next->value - ptr->value > 0) && !is_ascending))) {
    ...
}
```